Requirement to print the tr with className="onlyInLastPage" in the last page and just above the footer
I have a requirement, where i have to print the Doctor Prescription in A4 page or pages. Depending on the content it may take page or pages.
-> each page will have a header and footer which are fixed.
-> the height of A4 page is 297mm, out of that i gave top and bottom margin as 4mm. so reamining height of A4 page is 289mm. Out of that 289mm the header takes 55mm and footer takes 40mm.
-> i am sharing the code
-> header , footer all works fine
-> the issue is i want the     in last page of the A4 only and at just above the footer.


this is the css
/*this is for printing  */
@media print {
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 4mm;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0; 
    }
    .print-container table {
        width: 100%;
        /*margin:4mm;*/
    }
    .header-placeholder{
        height: 55mm;
    }
    .footer-placeholder{
        height: 40mm;
    }
    .header, .footer {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .header {
        top: 0;
    }
    .footer {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
<div ref={ref} className="print-container">
 <table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <td className="header-placeholder"></td>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr> 
        <td>
           <table>
              <tbody>
                   <tr> </tr>
                   <tr>  </tr>
           <tr> </tr>
            .
            .
            .
          <tr> </tr>
              <tr className="onlyInLastPage"> </tr>  
              </tbody>
           </table> 
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
     <tr>
        <td className="footer-placeholder"></td>
     </tr>
    </tfoot>
 </table>
 <div className="header">
      // header content
 </div>
  <div className="footer">
     <table>
        <tfoot>
           <tr>  </tr>
           <tr>  </tr>
        </tfoot>
     </table>
  </div> 
</div>




Could you better explain your problem please, and/or show an example of the issue?
